# Check if object is newly created or retrieved from database in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Ruby on Rails and i have a find_or_create_by_custom_stuff method. However i would like to know if the object i get back was found, or was created. Something like this

```
user = User.find_or_create_by_custom_stuff(params[:user])
if user.was_found_from_database?
  ...
elsif user.was_recently_created?
  ...
end
```

Is there any way I can do this without relying on the created_at timestamp of the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try not to use the find_or_create* method. The reason is that almost always the finder pattern will diverge from the creation one.

Another approach could be:

```
user = User.custom_finder(params)
if user.blank?
   user = User.create(params)
   #some business logic goes here
else
   #other business logic goes here
end
```

This could also be implemented into the User model for better structure

Comment: This is a better way to do it. Using `create` means that the new object will be persisted in the database, thus making it indistinguishable from a found object (unless you look at `created_at`, which would be very sloppy of you).

Comment: agreed, going to a find_or_new_by_whatever(...) makes more sense, thanks!

Comment: There is a `first_or_initialize` check here: https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize

Answer (score 16):

You have the ActiveRecord method for that

```
@instance.new_record?
```

For you

```
user = User.find_or_create(params[:user])
user.new_record?
```

Note :

```
.new_record? => NOT RECORDED IN DATABASE
```

Comment: .new_record? will, in this case, always return false (user is a DB created object after the User.find_or_create)

Comment: @Tamer Salama your are right ! My response it's false ! Your response work effectively, my apologizes...

Answer (score 0):

You can try find_or_initialize_by and then do the new_record? check. One thing to keep in mind is that a user could be created before you have the chance to save your new record. You also have that same issue with find_or_create_by but this might give a larger window for such a thing to happen.

```
user = User.find_or_initialize_by(email: params[:email])
if user.new_record?
  if user.save
    render json: user, status: :created
  else
    render json: { errors: @like.errors }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
else
  render json: user
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
user = User.find_or_create_by_custom_stuff(params[:user])
if user.new_record?
  # record does not exist in datastore
else
  ...
end
```

Comment: user.new_record? will always return true as it is a DB created object. find_or_create_* will attempt a find - and then if it doesn't exist will create one. hence, the returned object is a created record.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was thinking of `new`, not `create`. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
user_total = User.count
user = User.find_or_create_by_custom_stuff(params[:user])
if user_total == User.count
 #No new user was created, find method was used.
 ...
else
 #New user created, create method was used.
 ...
end
```